# Get all keys in a class in Parse-Server

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm writing a global search function (JS & Cloud Code), and I need to get all the available keys from a given class.

I tried extending a class and getting its object attributes

```
var Item = Parse.Object.extend("Item");
var item = new Item();
console.log(item.attributes);
```

But I'm getting an empty object.

If I retrieve an object from the database, either by get() or find(), I do get its keys, but only those which have values, and I need to retrieve all the keys in a given class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out! I can query the Schema of a class

```
var itemSchema = new Parse.Schema('Item');
itemSchema.get({
    success: function(schema) {

    },
    error: function(object, error) {

    }
});
```

And even get the schema of all my classes

```
Parse.Schema.all({
    success: function(schemas) {

    },
    error: function(object, error) {

    }
});
```

Hope this answer helps someone someday!